# Is there a way of reloading a View Controller upon completion of a function using Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am using the following syntax in a View Controller (using a Storyboard) to remove the second element of an array in a database.

```
@IBAction func deleteItemOne(_ sender: UIButton) {

if userId == user?.uid {
                        
  let group_array = document["product"] as? [String] ?? [""]
                        
    if  (group_array.count) > 1 {
            
      document.reference.updateData([
          "product": FieldValue.arrayRemove([group_array[1]])
      ])
                            self.viewDidLoad()
                            self.viewWillAppear(true)
         }
     }
}
```

Once the element of the array has been removed, I am using the following syntax to then reload the View Controller

```
self.viewDidLoad() 
self.viewWillAppear(true)
```

However after removal of the element, the View Controller doesn't reload as intended, and in-fact it doesn't end up doing anything.

This leads to my question, is there a simple Swift function / method that I can call to reload the View Controller upon completion?

Comment: Never ever call delegate methods containing `will`, `did` and `should` yourself. They are exclusively called by the framework. Reload the (table) view inside the closure, right after the `arrayRemove` line.

Answer (score 3):

You should never call viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear directly. The system calls those methods (and viewDidLoad only gets called once for the lifetime of a view controller.)

You should factor your code to have a `displayContents()` method (or similar.) Call that when you need to display contents, either initially, or whenever the contents change.

Comment: is the `displayContents()` method a Swift method? I just looked up this method and on the Apple Developer website it states that you shouldn't call a `display` method directly?

Comment: No, I am saying that you should define your own method, `displayContents()` that populates your view controller with data. You should call it when your view controller's data first becomes available, and then later if you have new data to display.

Comment: If you don't like the prefix "display", how about `showData()`